# Norm inequality in Schwartz class.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces, schwartz-space

Let $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, Schwartz class. Then is it true that, $$\|f\|_2\leq \|f\|_1$$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot be true. If this is  true then the inequality holds for all continuous functions with compact support and then for all $f \in L^{1}$. Hence $L^{1}$ would be contained in $L^{2}$ which is false.

Comment: Thanks @Kabo Murphy

Comment: No @reuns. Other way. Kabo was right.

Comment: Sure, sorry, and $\|1_{[0,1/n]}\|_{L^1} = 1/n,\|1_{[0,1/n]}\|_{L^2} = 1/n^{1/2}$, the Schwartz approximations are obtained from convolution with $k e^{-\pi k^2 x^2}$

Comment: @Kabo Murphy I have given you a particular function $f$ in Schwartz class. Why the inequality will be true for all continuous functions with compact support?

Comment: I have arrived at a contradiction assuming that the inequality holds for all $f$ in the Schwartz space. So there is at least one $f$ for which $\|f\|_2 >\|f\|_1$. @Prof.Hijibiji